# apache 2.4 disk cache not writing to cahce root

Tags: caching, disk, apache2.4, apache-modules

I did the setup of apache 2.4 with the below configurations

```
 ProxyPass      /       "http://localhost:9081/"
    ProxyPassReverse /     "http://localhost:9081/"
    <IfModule mod_cache.c>
            <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
            CacheRoot "/opt/apicache/"
            CacheDefaultExpire 3600
            CacheEnable disk "/"
            CacheDirLevels 2
            CacheDirLength 1
            CacheMaxFileSize 1000000
            CacheMinFileSize 1
            CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
            CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
            CacheIgnoreQueryString Off
            CacheIgnoreHeaders None
            CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.1
            CacheDefaultExpire 3600
            CacheMaxExpire 86400
            CacheStoreNoStore On
            CacheStorePrivate On
            # Enable the X-Cache-Detail header
            CacheDetailHeader on
            </IfModule>
            </IfModule>
```

Also I changed the CacheRoot Permission by following

```
mkdir -p /opt/apicache/
chown root:www-data /opt/apicache/ -R
chmod 775 /opt/apicache/ -R
```

apache log level is set debug

```
LogLevel debug
```

Quite not sure why apache 2.4 not caching anything to the cache root and also does not show any logs in error logs

Comment: Maybe those modules aren't loaded. Why would you bother with IfModule?

Comment: I can see cache modules are loaded with the below command . Ignore the fully qualified name error  
`root@INMHPUUBUNTU14:# ./apachectl -M
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using INMHPUUBUNTU14.04LAP08. Set the ' ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
.
 **cache_module (shared)**
 **cache_disk_module (shared)**
..
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared) `

Answer (score 0):

make sure apache can write to `/opt/apicache/`

```
chmod 766 /opt/apicache/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cache was not working because the page size was greater than the CacheMaxFileSize.

Comment: It can be a comment since there is no detailed answer provided